# class is not nothrow constructible but is nothrow destructible

Tags: c++, constructor, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a class like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( )
    : m_member1( 1 ), m_member2( 2 ), m_member3( std::vector<char>( 1 * 2, '-' ) )
    {
    }

    // ~Foo( ) is not defined (i.e. implicitly declared by the compiler)

private:
    int m_member1;
    int m_member2;
    std::vector<char> m_member3;
};

int main( )
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "is nothrow constructible? " << std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<Foo> << '\n'
                                << "is nothrow destructible? " << std::destructible<Foo> << '\n';
}
```

In the above code, I took advantage of a C++20 concept (`std::destructible<T>`) to gain some more info about the aforementioned class.

Output:

```
is nothrow constructible? false
is nothrow destructible? true
```

I understand the reason why it's not **nothrow constructible**. E.g. the constructor of `std::vector` can throw an `std::bad_alloc`, etc. But why is the destructor **nothrow** too?
Now if the implicit destructor is **nothrow**, then would it be better if I marked the destructor `noexcept` in case I wrote an explicit definition?

Comment: Have a read on how to make a [mre]. Making your code a few lines shorted by not including proper includes and a main function only hurts your question. Also, [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/4qz3EnsY5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructors are special. For the implicit destructor as well as user-declared destructors without `noexcept` specification, the destructor is `noexcept(true)` by default if all destructors of members and base classes are `noexcept(true)`.

To get a potentially-throwing destructor, you need to explicitly declare it `noexcept(false)`. This is however generally not what one wants, since there will be trouble if the destructor throws while stack unwinding from another exception is in progress.

For ordinary functions, usually the default is `noexcept(false)`, meaning potentially-throwing, if not declared otherwise.

There are a few additional special cases of this kind though, e.g. deallocation functions and (member) functions defaulted on their first declaration.

Comment: `defaulted functions`, do you mean defaulted member functions?

Comment: @digito_evo Yes, I think there are no other functions that can be defaulted.

Comment: Now what I don't quite understand is how deallocating a vector is a nothrow operation. When calling `delete[]`, does it never throw?

Comment: @digito_evo A deallocation function is specifically a function named `operator delete` which delete-expressions call internally to deallocate the memory that was obtained by a new-expression via a call to an allocation function (`operator new`). These really shouldn't throw exceptions, because what happens to the memory when trying to free it fails? In fact the standard says that a deallocation function throwing an exception causes undefined behavior. Therefore they are `noexcept(true)` by default.

Comment: @digito_evo I misread your comment. You weren't asking about the deallocation function. Sorry. `std::vector` doesn't throw when it is destroyed, because freeing memory itself should never throw exceptions, see above. The only other case that it could throw is if the destructor of one of the elements throws, but it is not allowed to throw from destructors of elements used in the vector and more generally it is almost never permitted to throw exceptions from destructors used with the standard library, see https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.functions#2.4